# How to switch between fragments in android like drawer menu without FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In Android Studio 4, Create a project with Navigation Drawer Activity template and want to put a button to change fragment programmatically.

After some researching I found that there should be a FrameLayout that with below codes can change fragment easily:

```
Fragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

But the problem is that there is no FrameLayout in the project layouts and other files types.

The question is that without this how drawer menu can work to switch between fragments?

I want to switch between fragments like Drawer menu way, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) as the template does, you should [navigate to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) by calling `navigate()` - this is precisely what the `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` is doing for you when you tap on an item in the `NavigationView` via [`NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI?hl=en#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)).

You do not use a `FragmentTransaction` at all when using the Navigation Component.